# Convert SQL datetime to C# string

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I'm trying to convert the ReturnDate to a string. As of now it's stored in the database as a Datetime and I wish to convert to a string in C#.

```
 [Display(Name = "Return Date")]
        public string ReturnDate
        {
            get { return this._ReturnDate; }
            set { this._ReturnDate = value; }
        }

 loan._ReturnDate = dar["ReturnDate"] as string;
```

Comment: Why would you not use a property of type `DateTime` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
loan._ReturnDate = ((DateTime)dar["ReturnDate"]).ToString();
```

You can find the datetime format for the ToString() from @Grant Winney's comment.